# Xcode IPhone Parse Server Output

Tags: iphone, xcode, string, parsing

I am sending some data to the server that is coming back as a string, but i need to parse it at the carriage return (new line)

The variable the output is being stored in is

```
NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: dataurl encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

The output is:
1bac92c2-b83a-4c93-9e11-831115825fa9\nmike1\nmike2\nfoo@bar.ca\n2

Any suggestions or help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
NSString *serverOutput = @"1bac92c2-b83a-4c93-9e11-831115825fa9\nmike1\nmike2\nfoo@bar.ca\n2";
NSArray *myData = [serverOutput componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```